# MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012) does not recognise Yamaha YHT-1840

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, hdmi, displayport

I connected my MacBook using MiniDisplay+HDMI cable to input port on a receiver.
I connected my Projector to output port on receiver.

All works great I can see a video and I can hear 5.1 audio.

But when I switch off a projector or unplug it at all MacBook stop seeing a receiver.

I would like to play just music for example without running projector.

When I switch off projector the output looks like this:
[image]

Do I need projector to be switched on every time to hear a sound?